# SQL code editor with syntax highlighing, auto-formatting and code folding

Tags: sql, editor, code-formatting, folding

Is there any SQL editor that supports syntax highlighting, automatic code formatting and code folding? I found [this](http://plsqleditor.sourceforge.net/), but it's an Eclipse plugin (I'm a NetBeans user), and cannot automatically format code, which is the most important feature I'm after.

Autocompletion is not important, nor is the possibility of running the code (like the SQL editor in NetBeans).

**Edit:** I'm sorry for not specifying, I'm looking for Linux or even web-based software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQuirreL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) ticks a lot of your boxes, and has [formatting and other plugins](http://www.squirrelsql.org/index.php?page=plugins) and runs on Linux

I'd give it a try at least

Comment: Wow, I installed it, installed the MySQL JDBC connector, and it works perfectly! Thank you! I will accept this answer as soon as SO lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

[Programmers Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/) is a nice little application.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm interested in a Linux or web-based program.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you there :)

Answer (score 1):

Online SQL Formater http://sqlserverlearner.com/online-tools/tsql-code-formatter

Answer (score 0):

Use VIM.

See this link on how to set it up:

http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Vim-HOWTO.html

Comment: 2Cobusve: vim on itself does not do any SQL code formatting, it requires a plugin, e.g. this one: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=492

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [QweryBuilder](http://www.werysoft.com). It supports syntax highlighting, automatic code formatting, code folding and auto completion.